# different colors in a list of values that are in a TextView

Tags: android, colors, textview

My question is I have a `TextView` with different values​​, for example:
-1.7
+5,8
-3,3
 0,0
+7,7

With the code that I did just take the first negative value and leaves me all the same color.

This is my code:

Activity:

```
    List<ParsedExampleDataSet5101> parsedExampleDataSetList = 
                myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

        for(ParsedExampleDataSet5101 parsedExampleDataSet : parsedExampleDataSetList){

            tv.append(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());
            tv1.append(parsedExampleDataSet.toString1());
                    tv2.append(parsedExampleDataSet.toString2());
            tv3.append(parsedExampleDataSet.toString3());   

            if (parsedExampleDataSet.toString2().contains("-")){
                tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            }else{
                tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
            }

        }
```

`ParsedExampleDataSet5101` is an other class, I have in this class the getters and setters and `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple HTML to format texts in TextView as far as I know, so you could try something like `<span style="color:#FF0000">first value</span><span style="color:#008000">next value</span>`.

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
for(ParsedExampleDataSet5101 parsedExampleDataSet : parsedExampleDataSetList){
    if (parsedExampleDataSet.toString2().contains("-")) {
        s.append("<span style="color:#FF0000">")
    } else {
        s.append("<span style="color:#008000">")
    }
    s.append(parsedExampleDataSet.toString2());
    s.append("</span>");
}
tv.setText(s.toString()); // <-- supposing tv is your TextView object
```

Comment: I seek to make is that if it is a negative value, the color is red and if positive is green

Comment: No this is just an example. You'd have to go through the parts of your strings as you do, and build up a String, perhaps using a StringBuffer. See edited answer.

Comment: Strings are not helping. You need a Spanned, Spannable or in this case a SpannableStringBuilder. You also need to use Html.fromHtml to apply styling information. See my answer for an example based on edwin's original code.

Answer (score 0):

Ridcully is basically right, though his answer is not complete - and the span tag is also not supported.

You can use HTML in Textviews, but you have to create a Spanned (subclass of CharSequence) that contains the formatting information.

You create a Spanned by using Html.fromHtml(). For details on HTML formatting in TextViews, see my post
[Formatting text with Html.fromHtml()](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-quick-tip-formatting-text-with-html-fromhtml/)

So you could do something like this:

```
  if (parsedExampleDataSet.toString2().startsWith("-")){
     tv2.append(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + parsedExampleDataSet.toString2() + "</font>"));
  }else{
     tv2.append(parsedExampleDataSet.toString2());
  }
```

Comment: I'm not a native speaker. Maybe I got your question wrong. I assumed from the code given above that you have something parsed and transformed into a List of a known type. The Html.fromHtml(String str) operates on a String and supports only a subset of HTML (see my blogpost, that is linked within my answer). So you would have to download the XML and transfer it into something usable - a simple String containing some HTML formatting.

Comment: Yeah, Wolfram is right -- My answer was just from off my head, without lookup up the details.

Comment: Any comments, edwin? Anything still missing?